# How to bypass sending email in Auth0 change password flow with old password confirmation?

Tags: angular, auth0, change-password

I want to build a custom page for change password with auth0. The flow must be directly changing password without sending an email which has change password screen link. And there should be provision to confirm old password.

I have tried with the following code in Angular 2

```
auth0.changePassword({
connection:'db-conn',
username:'example@ex.com'
password:'blahblah'
},() => {});
```

But this is throwing an error **Password not allowed**
 as it is deprecated in latest version.

Is there any other way to implement this?or any other api to call?

Comment: Am working on a demonstration pOC for this and shall share link once completed.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below a link to a Github Repository with a working webtask sample that demonstrates how you can achieve password reset in the way you described.

Requires the user to verify their old password (by supplying their email (username) and existing password, and the new password / repeat new password combination. Finally, if verification is successful then updates their password without issuing a password reset email confirmation.

[auth0-change-password-custom-verification](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-change-password-custom-verification)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.This is using Auth0 API v2 which is used by backend right? My requirement is to have some api call using lock widget to get this done.Is there anything to support this.

Comment: Re. backend and api v2 - yes. Re. auth0.js / lock, there is this, which I think you already know about, but it will send email with link. This is a flow I think you wish to avoid? https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js#change-password-database-connections

Comment: You can pass this attribute into Lock widget `forgotPasswordLink` and give it a value of the URL to the above webtask. This way, you continue to use Lock widget, but get the custom password reset flow you wanted.

Comment: See here for details on Lock DB settings - https://github.com/auth0/lock#database-options